# PowerShell - Exclude text on Select-String

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell script to list down all the AV installed on a machine. I wanted to exclude the Windows Defender on the "If" statement when doing the checks. Below is my script:

```
   default
       {
       $result1 = 'There are {0} AV products installed on this system' -f $AVList.Count
       $result2 = 'DisplayNames = {0}' -f ($AVList.displayName -join ', ')
       if (Select-String -Path $workingdirectory\AVList.txt -Pattern $AVList.displayName -Exclude 'Windows Defender' -SimpleMatch -Quiet){
       $writeTxt4 = ("$(Get-Date) - [INFO]",'There are {0} AV products installed on this system.' -f $AVList.Count)
       $writeTxt5 = ("$(Get-Date) - [INFO]",'Anti-Virus Names = {0}' -f ($AVList.displayName -join ', '))
       Write-Output $writeTxt4 $writeTxt5
       Add-Content -path $report $writeTxt4
       Add-Content -path $report $writeTxt5
       }else{
       $writeTxt4 = ("$(Get-Date) - [INFO]",'There are {0} AV products installed on this system. Smile.' -f $AVList.Count)
       $writeTxt5 = ("$(Get-Date) - [INFO]",'Anti-Virus Names = {0}' -f ($AVList.displayName -join ', '))
       Write-Output $writeTxt4 $writeTxt5
         Add-Content -path $report $writeTxt4
       Add-Content -path $report $writeTxt5
       }
```

I tried to exclude it but still unable to make it work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've now reduced it. basically, how can I exclude the Windows Defender on the select string test. On the AVList result, I got two AV showing up, BitDefender and Windows Defender.

Comment: if `$AVList.displayName` contains `Windows Defender` then what you are doing won't work. By the way, this is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: correct the `$AVList.displayName` contains `Windows Defender`.  any idea how can I exclude it from the condition? Also, that's the main goal of my concern. thank you.

Comment: just filter `$AVList.displayName` to all elements where they don't match "Windows Defender" before passing it to `Select-String`

Comment: As @SantiagoSquarzon sayd: just filter Windows Defender out from the start: `$AVList = @(Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root/SecurityCenter2' -ClassName 'AntivirusProduct' | Where-Object { $_.displayName -notlike '*Windows Defender*'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference of `Select-String`, parameter [`-Exclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string#parameters):

> Exclude the specified items. The value of this parameter **qualifies the
> Path parameter**. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt.
> Wildcards are permitted.

So this is not what we need here.

As noted in the comments, you should filter `$AVList` instead:

```
# Get all AV's, excluding "Windows Defender"
$filteredAvList = @($AVList.displayName) -notlike '*Windows Defender*'

if (Select-String -Path $workingdirectory\AVList.txt -Pattern $filteredAvList -SimpleMatch -Quiet){
    # TODO: Replace $avList by $filteredAvList 
}
```

When a [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) like `-notlike` is applied to a collection, it effectively [filters the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features), returning only the elements that match the condition. To make sure that the operator is always applied to an array, enclose the LHS operand with the [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) `@()`. Otherwise you would get a boolean result when the LHS is a single object.

Comment: thanks @zett42. I just did some adjustment and was able to make it work now. here's the updated script:

`$filteredAvList = @($AVList.displayName) -notlike '*Windows Defender*'`
`if (Select-String -Path $workingdirectory\AVList.txt -Pattern $filteredAvList.displayName -SimpleMatch -Quiet){`

Comment: @IamBayMax Thanks for the correction, I've updated my answer. The `Select-String` call is not right in your comment, it should be `-Pattern $filteredAvList`, because `$filteredAvList` is just an array of strings now.

Comment: i tried to use the `-Pattern $filteredAvList` and for some reason, not working, so I used `$filteredAvList.displayName` but yeah the good thing is that it is now doing what I want. thank you so much